# how to set pointer to a memory to NULL using memset?

Tags: c++, null, pointers, memset

I have a structure

```
typedef struct my_s {

   int x;
   ...
} my_T;

my_t * p_my_t;
```

I want to set the address of `p_my_t` to `NULL` and so far this is how I've tried to do this:

```
memset (&p_my_t, 0, sizeof(my_t*))
```

This doesn't not look right to me though. What is the correct way of doing this?

---

*Amendment to question - asking a radically more complex question*:

Here is what I am trying to do:

- Two processes, A and B
- malloc p_my_t in A, B has N threads and can access it
- Start deleting in A but I can not simply free it since threads in B may still using it.
- So I call a function, pass address of p_my_t to B to set its address to NULL in B so no other threads in B can use anymore
- After call back from B, I then free memory in A

*NB: there is no standard way to manage memory allocations via shared memory between processes.  You will have to do some rather careful thinking about what is going on.*

Comment: Are you trying to set p_my_t to NULL, or are you trying to set the address of p_my_t to NULL?

Comment: set the address of p_my_t to NULL

Comment: @dave: you cannot set the address of p_my_t to NULL (p_my_t is a name for a memory location); you can set the value of p_my_t to NULL, so it is known not to point anywhere.

Comment: @dave: also, you should not use _t as a suffix on variable names.  It is not a particularly good idea to use it for types (POSIX reserves type names ending _t for the implementation's use), but it is downright confusing to have a variable ending _t.

Answer (score 21):

Don't use `memset` to initialize a null pointer as this will set the memory to all bits zero which is not guaranteed to be the representation of a null pointer, just do this:

```
p_my_t = NULL;
```

or the equivalent:

```
p_my_t = 0;
```

Comment: Recommended code is usually using 0 directly instead of NULL. 0 is just as expressive as NULL and it does not require the macro or its definition.

Comment: Recommended by who?  0 is not as "expressive" as NULL, i = NULL makes it clear that i is a pointer, i = 0 doesn't.

Comment: In C++, NULL is defined to be 0, so the "i = NULL makes it clear that i is a pointer" is not enforced by the compiler. C++0x has nullptr, and that is indeed enforced.

Comment: The point is that it makes it clear to the human reading your code.

Comment: It is better to use NULL.  It is more readable and, in the slim chance that the definition of NULL changes, your code will not break.

Comment: I agree with using NULL, but the definition of NULL will not change. It is required by the standard to be 0 (although that may not correspond to setting all bits to zero, as Robert Gamble pointed out)

Comment: The standard guarantees that 0 will be converted to the correct bit-pattern for a null pointer. It says nothing about NULL. NULL is just there for backward compatibility with C code.

Comment: @Ferruccio: Don't be silly, if NULL is defined as 0 then i = NULL will be turned into i = 0 by the preprocessor with the same guarantee as if it were written as i = 0 to begin with.

Comment: Updated answer to include both versions.

Comment: The memset and uninitialized static/global variable for NULL has become so common that any new architectures will dare not violate it.

Comment: @jalf: I agree that NULL won't likely change but this reminds me of the famous quote from the Xerox Fortran manual when discussing the advantages of using the DATA statement (which is similar to using a preprocessor macro):

Comment: "Instead of referring to PI as 3.141592653589797, at every appearance,
the variable PI can be given that value with a DATA statement, and
used instead of the longer form of the constant. This also simplifies
modifying the program, should the value of PI change."

Comment: @Joshua: 1) In my experience it isn't at all common to use memset to initialize pointer variables, and 2) uninitialized static/global pointer variables are guaranteed to be initialized to NULL in C, I assume the same is true in C++.

Comment: Why the down-vote?  At least explain what is wrong with the answer.

Comment: i would say neither NULL nor 0 is better. points can be made for either one. some people prefer 0, some prefer NULL. and yeah uninitialized static storage is initialized with NULL in C++ too, and not all bits 0 necassary.

Comment: Stroustrup doesn't use NULL. And if you're going to use a macro, as he points out, why would you use NULL instead of the forward looking nullptr???

Comment: Arguments for using NULL have already been well made here.  The bottom line is that NULL and 0 both work on all platforms *today*, there is nothing wrong with either one, your downvote is petty.

Comment: The problem with not using a more expressive form than 0 is that it takes more effort for the human who has to maintain the code to understand the usage.  Are you setting a number, pointer, character etc. to 0?   nullptr seems like the win from now on.

Answer (score 4):

What exactly are you trying to do?  `p_my_t` is already a pointer, but you haven't allocated memory for it.  If you want to set the pointer to NULL, simply do

```
p_my_t = NULL;
```

Trying to dereference this pointer will result in a segmentation fault (or access violation on Windows).

Once the pointer actually pointers to something (e.g. via `malloc()` or by assigning to it the address of a `struct my_T`), then you can properly `memset()` it:

```
memset(p_my_t, 0, sizeof(struct my_T));
```

This will zero out the entire structure, setting all fields to zero.

Comment: thanks, adding comments here has limitation, so please see my "answer posting"

Answer (score 2):

The recommended code for setting a pointer to *null* is assigning 0 (zero). Bjarne Stroustrup [does](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#null) it :) Anyway it is just as expressive as NULL and does not depend on a macro definition.

Note that NULL is not a keyword, it is not reserved and while it would be confusing to redefine, nothing says that you should not (more than style). A coworker often jokes about defining NULL to something different than 0 in some header just to see how other people's code behave.

In the upcoming standard there will be a more expressive *nullptr* keyword to identify a null pointer.

Comment: actually, it effectively forbids redefining NULL. you are not allowed to #undef NULL because it is reserved once you include a std header that defines it.

Comment: NULL is better! The next c++ standard will have a new object nullptr.  There are issues when using 0 (converting an int to a pointer), nullptr will solve them.  In gcc NULL is defined as __null.  Once nullptr becomes standard, change NULL from 0 to nullptr; all the benefits with no changes for you.

Answer (score 2):

I think maybe you want

```
extern void set_t_pointer_to_null(my_T *pp);
```

and call

```
set_t_pointer_to_null(&p_my_t);
```

where

```
void set_t_pointer_to_null(my_T *pp) { *pp = NULL; }
```

I'm not sure it's worth defining a function to do this, but I think this answers the question you're trying to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, here is what I an trying to do

- two processes, A and B
- malloc p_my_t in A, B has N threads and can access it
- start deleting in A but I can not simply free it since threads in B may still using.
- so I call a function, pass address of p_my_t to B to set its address to NULL in B so no others threads in B can use anymore
- After call back from B, I then free memory in A

Comment: you should probably add this info to your question, or rephrase it - however it doesn't sound right as you've described it here. Unless the pointer is to shared memory, how can it be shared across processes?

Comment: I agree this is different than the original question.  You should pose this as a separate question, since the answer to the question you actually asked is just p_my_t = NULL;

Comment: @dave: how do the two processes get to share the memory?  This is a vastly different question from what you originally asked.

Answer (score 0):

Per your reply (elsewhere in this post) stating:

> Thanks, here is what I an trying to do
>
> - two processes, A and B
> - malloc `p_my_t` in A, B has N threads and can access it
> - start deleting in A but I can not simply free it since threads in B may still using.
> - so I call a function, pass address of `p_my_t` to B to set its address to NULL in B so no others threads in B can use anymore
> - After call back from B, I then free memory in A

What you need is some form of synchronization between all your threads and processes.  I'm not sure of how you are sharing this object between processes, but I suspect you are using shared memory.

Normally I would recommend using a shared pointer class (such as Boost's `shared_ptr` class), but I'm not sure of how well that would work in this scenario.  You may want to consider tweaking your class so that it tracks its own references and can be used with the Boost `intrusive_ptr` class.

That way, process A can simply forget about the object, and when process B is finished, the instance of `my_T` will know that there are no more references left and clean itself up.

The synchronization would come into play here when `my_T` is adding or removing references internally (so you don't run into nasty race conditions where it thinks it should clean itself up but is really still in use).

One other approach that has a bit more of a "kluge" feel to it is to give each instance of `my_T` an "is-valid" flag so that all processes/threads using it will know whether or not to continue doing so.

For more details on Boost's various pointer classes, check out [their documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm).

Comment: You could also use the TR1 shared_ptr class that was previously available in boost.  This will allow you to delete the pointer in B without worrying what A is doing.  

More information on shared_ptr: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm

Answer (score 0):

From reading your multi-thread comments I should say there is *no* safe sequence of code to accomplish your task. You will have to step back and reexamine your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, memset won't solve your problem. If A and B are separate processes, then `p_my_t` in process A will be different form `p_my_t` in process B. You just can't pass a pointer between different processes. I sugest you use some kind of IPC mechanism in order to sinchronyze your two processes (message queues, for example), and just using `p_my_t = NULL` instead of memset.

Answer (score 0):

Per your update, it seems to me that what you are really trying to do is guard access to a resource, which means you should use a read/write lock that is shared between the processes to guard the ptr to that resource, and test the ptr before using.

- Allocate the structure in shared memory.
- Allocate the ptr to the structure in shared memory.
- Guard access to the ptr to the structure with a Read/Write lock.
- Process A should acquire a WRITE lock to the ptr when initializing or invalidating the ptr and structure.
- Process B should acquire a READ lock to the ptr, and test that the ptr is valid before using the structure