# How to initialize variables for struct sockaddr_in

Tags: c, sockets

When I initialize variables, I do bellow.

```
int i = 0;
char *myText = NULL;
```

Then, haw can I initialize `struct sockaddr_in` type variables?

```
struct sockaddr_in addr = ?;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to set all fields to zero in a declaration, no matter the structure, then do e.g.

```
struct some_struct var = { 0 };
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use `memset`

Lets say you want to initialize the entire addr structure variable to 0, you can do it as follows.

```
memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
```

If you want to initialize it using different values you can refer to the example here

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/12/c-socket-programming/

Comment: This might not apply to `sockaddr_in`, but one must be careful when `memset`ting the `struct`s. If `struct` has pointer members, those should be assigned to `NULL` by hand.

Comment: @user694733 No it's not needed. Setting a pointer to zero and setting to `NULL` is the same. In C, `NULL` is usually a macro defined as `((void *) 0)`.

Comment: NULL is defined as `#define NULL ((char *)0)`, so the above still holds good.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg But what if bit representation of `NULL` is not all bits zero? `memset` doesn't know what data types of the bytes it is zeroing, so it wouldn't know to handle those specific bytes differently. [See this answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/398897/694733)

Comment: @user376507 That is irrelevant. See my comment to JoachimPileborg.

Comment: @user694733 From the C11 specification (§6.3.2.3/3): "An integer constant expression with the value `0`, or such an expression cast to type `void *`, is called a null pointer constant", with the footnote "The macro NULL is defined in <stddef.h> (and other eaders) as a null pointer constant". This means that a null pointer, and therefore `NULL` is defined to be zero.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, I not arguing that. But runtime bit representation of NULL is implementation defined. Compiler will do the magic and convert `NULL` or `0` to `0xDEADC0DE` (for example) when it is assigned to the pointer. `memset` on the other hand happens at runtime, and doesn't know to do that conversion, because it operates only on bunch of bytes, and doesn't know the underlying data types.

Comment: @user694733 As you said it’ll segmentation fault when I print pointer after memset structure type or using {0} Joachim Pileborg’s answer. Tell me how to set NULL to the pointer in structure type.

Comment: @user694733 This happens if I use `protoent` structure.I’m doing print for `char **p_aliase` in `protoent` with `printf(“pointer = %s\n",*protoent.p_aliases)` .It’ll be segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bzero on unix-like os. e.g:

bzero(&addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

Comment: No, you shouldn't be using bzero(), this is from bzero's entry in man pages:                       A bzero() function appeared in 4.3BSD.<br/>Its prototype existed previously in <string.h> before it was moved to <strings.h> for IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 (``POSIX.1'') compliance.

     bzero() was deprecated in IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 (``POSIX.1'') and removed in IEEE Std 1003.1-2008 (``POSIX.1'').

Answer (score 0):

This is what I tend to do

```
struct sockaddr_in addr = {.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY)};
```

if you want to re-initialize the variable

```
struct sockaddr_in addr;

addr = (struct sockaddr_in) {.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY)};
```

This makes use of [Designated Initializers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html)