# Correct Way To Modify Existing Code To Loop Through Subnet

Tags: c, subnet, port-scanning

I'm writing a port scanner with the intent to loop through an entire subnet to see if port 445 is open on any of the hosts as a way to learn C programming. The way that this program is currently setup, one needs to manually enter in a single IP address, and the scanner fires off. It is working perfectly (finally).

The current issue I'm facing: I'm not sure how to approach making this program scan an entire subnet, rather than just a single host. After researching this question, I believe the best route to pursue would be stripping off the last octet of the IP address, and having it loop from 1-254. However, I'm not entirely sure how to begin approaching this issue. This is my current code (heavily commented for clarification):

```
...
void portScan() {

struct hostent *host;
    int err, i , sock ,start , end;
    char hostname[100];
    struct sockaddr_in sa;

    //Get the hostname to scan
    printf("Enter hostname or IP to scan: ");
    gets(hostname);

    //Get start port number
    start = 445;

    //Get end port number
    end = 445;

    //Initialise the sockaddr_in structure
    strncpy((char*)&sa , "" , sizeof sa);
    sa.sin_family = AF_INET;

    //direct ip address, use it
    if(isdigit(hostname[0])) {
        sa.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(hostname);
    }

    //Start the port scan loop
    printf("Starting the portscan loop : \n");

    for( i = start ; i <= end ; i++) {
        //Fill in the port number
        sa.sin_port = htons(i);

        //Create a socket of type internet
        sock = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);

        //Check whether socket was created or not
        if(sock < 0) {
            perror("\nSocket");
            exit(1);
        }
        //Connect using that socket and sockaddr structure
        err = connect(sock , (struct sockaddr*)&sa , sizeof sa);

        //not connected
        if(err < 0) {
            //printf("%s %-5d %s\r" , hostname , i, strerror(errno));
            fflush(stdout);
        }
        //connected
        else {
            printf("%-5d open\n",  i);
        }
        close(sock);
    }

    printf("\r");
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

TL;DR: I'm not sure how to approach modifying this code to strip the last octet of the IP address, and loop through the subnet by replacing the last octet with a 1 - 254. Any feedback, ideas or help is highly appreciated! Still highly junior in the C world.

Comment: `strncpy` from a null string makes no sense.  Did you mean [`memset` or `=0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20651531/how-to-initialize-variables-for-struct-sockaddr-in)?

Comment: @DavisHerring Ah interesting, thank you for the feedback and catching that! Looking into the details of that right now.

Comment: You are asking the question, so what was too long that you didn't read (`TL;DR:`)??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The subnets are not just "the last byte". Instead in CIDR there is a prefix length/subnet mask. You just need one address from the subnet, and the *subnet mask* as *unsigned integers*, but in the **host byte order**, (you need to use `ntohl` on the return value of `inet_addr` and `htonl` to convert the integer again into an address that can be stored into `s_addr`).

- You `&` the host address with the *subnet mask* to get the network address.
- You `|` the network address with the *inverse* of the mask to get the broadcast address.
- The host addresses *within the network* are all the numbers that are in between these 2, so you can write a for loop that starts from `network_address + 1` and ends with `broadcast_address - 1`.

So, if your host address is 10.24.41.169 and prefix length is `23`, the address in hex is **0x0A1829A9**. The netmask has 23 first bits set to 1 and rest to 0, i.e. `0b11111111111111111111111000000000`, i.e. `0xFFFFFE00` in hex.

```
uint32_t host = 0x0A1829A9;
uint32_t netmask = 0xFFFFFE00;
```

Now the network address is `host & netmask`:

```
uint32_t network_address = host & netmask;
```

And broadcast address is `network_address | ~netmask;` or `host_address | ~netmask`:

```
uint32_t network_address = host_address | ~netmask;
```

The addresses within the subnet can be generated by a rather brainless `for` loop

```
for (uint32_t address = network_address + 1; address < broadcast_address; address ++) {
}
```

---

And from Davis Herring, to convert the prefix length to subnet mask, you can use

```
uint32_t netmask = ~(((uint32_t)1 << len) - 1);
```

Comment: Given a prefix `len`, you can make the netmask with `~((1u<<len)-1u)`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the incredibly helpful answer!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways I could see approaching this, it's nice since you have the IP at your disposal due to the initial input. However I feel this thread may point you in the right direction:
[How to increment an IP address in a loop? [C]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18257273/how-to-increment-an-ip-address-in-a-loop-c)

Let me know.

Comment: I think the better link is to https://stackoverflow.com/q/6743438/8586227.