# How do I empty an static array of string in C

Tags: c

I am using a global array of string of fixed size to store input from stdin temporarily. I am taking input from stdin in while loop. I wish to  store each line in that global array and empty it after it processes the first line, and for another line also I would like to use same array. below is my high level code

```
 char *tempArra[100];
  char line[1024];

 while(1){
      if (!fgets(line, 1024, stdin))
          return 0;
   // tokenize line and store in  tempArray
   //after done processing that line, empty tempArray to process anotherline

  }
```

I tried **memset(temparray, '\0', 100);** did not work. Any help please?

Comment: Show the full code, how you "tokenize" it.

Comment: Why do you want to be able to store all the lines in the global array if you're going to clear it once you've processed the first line? Surely you only need to be able to store one line whilst it's being processed?

Comment: I would guess the `tempArray` is just a bunch of pointers from `strtok`, which are actually pointing to places in `line`.

Comment: Please: more code!

Comment: @SteveSummit  yes, line is one array which i forgot to mention

Comment: You've got a mismatch between your declaration of `line` and how you use it in `fgets` - both should either be 1024 or 127

Comment: Bottom line, you don't need to clear it.  Just overwrite it when you read the next line.

Comment: Umm... 127 != 1024. How do you do the tokenization? How do you store it into a tempArray?

Comment: usually one stores the number of valid items; one "clears" the array by setting the number of valid items to 0

Comment: If you really want to "clear" it, it'd be `for(i = 0; i < n; i++) tempArra[i] = NULL;`, where `n` is the number of tokens you stored in it last time.  But you don't really need to do that; nothing will go wrong if you don't.

Comment: @SteveSummit I am going to try for loop and set it to NULL thanks

Comment: I have a feeling that it is an XY-problem.

Comment: This question should be closed for lack of [mcve]. All of the answers and comments are based on speculations about the invisible code.

Comment: `memset(temparray, '\0', 100);` zero 100 bytes.  Certainly `char *tempArra[100];` size exceeds 100 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line where you do the memset:

```
memset(temparray, '\0', 100);
```

uses a different variable name (*tempArra* is not the same variable as *temparray*). Try this instead:

```
memset(tempArra, 0, sizeof(tempArra));
```

Comment: I think `tempArra` is supposed to be an array of pointers into `line`. But there isn't enough info in the OP to be positive.

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT:

make all pointers NULL

```
memset(tempArra, 0, sizeof(tempArra));
```

if you want to make the `line` string zero length

```
 line[0] = 0;
```

or to zero it completely

```
 memset(line, 0, size of the `line`);
```

---

## before edit

You had to allocate the memory first : for example

```
 tempArra[x] = malloc(something);
```

Then you need to free it

```
 free(tempArra[x]);
```

Yo can also assign the NULL vaslue to the element of the array to mark it as free

```
 tempArra[x] = NULL;
```

Comment: Setting all bits to zero does not guarantee NULL pointers.

Comment: Does on all existing machines and the loop with the NULL assignment is compiled to the single memset on ALL modern machines. In theory the cast `(void *)0` is implementation defined, but in the real world I did not see such a implementation.

Comment: @machine_1 Curious, what platform, if any, do you know of where setting all bits to zero does not result in a _null pointer_?

Comment: @chux check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398883/how-to-set-pointer-to-a-memory-to-null-using-memset) link, but it's C++.

Comment: @machine_1 That link does not identify any platform  where setting all bits to zero would not result in a _null pointer_ - as  asked in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50513788/how-do-i-empty-an-static-array-of-string-in-c/50513866?noredirect=1#comment88040880_50513866).

Comment: @machine_1 C standard is designed to cover all imaginable machine architectures. I can imagine a death machine where different types of pointers have completely different size, format and address space. I can imagine the machine which memory looks like a swiss cheese - full of holes etc etc. The opinions there are about the hypothetical abstract machine. But in the real life no one designs them. So answer the **chux**s question - if you know any implementation where memsetiing the pointer to zero does not make it NULL or delete your comments.

Comment: I don't. No. But one should not think of the implementations. One must refer to the standard in these cases.

Comment: @machine_1 any known implementation? Please answer the question.

Comment: I said in my comment: No...

Comment: @machine_1 so - another question. What is the probability that the code will now work as expected?

Comment: I mentioned that in my comment also. One should not think of it this way.

Comment: Please do not use any devices which have embedded uCs in it. Almost all "one"s who have designed and programmed them, think that way. Your point has no practical importance.

Answer (score 0):

your array is an array of piointers to nowhere. YOu need to allocate and *then* copy. `strdup` will do it for you

```
  char *tempArra[100];
  char line[1024];
int i = 0;
 while(1){
      if (!fgets(line, 1024, stdin))
          return 0;
   // tokenize line and store in  tempArray
   //after done processing that line, empty tempArray to process anotherline
    tempArra[i++] = strdup(line); <<<<<<<

  }
```

Comment: No. He wrote that the pointers reference one of the elements of the  line array.